# FullCalendar showing event in month view but not day, week, or resource view

Tags: php, jquery, json, resources, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar Sean Kenny's fork to add a resource view.

[Source web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpqNz.jpg)

the problem is some events are just displayed under the month view, not in week or resource view.

**allDay is set to false for all events**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,resourceDay'
    },
 monthNames: ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ], 
 monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
 dayNames: [ 'Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sab'],
 buttonText: {
  today: 'hoy',
  month: 'mes',
  week: 'semana',
  day: 'dia'
 },
 allDaySlot : false,
 slotDuration: '00:15:00',
 axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
 firstDay : 1,
 minTime: '09:00:00',
 maxTime: '20:00:00',
    defaultView: 'resourceDay',
 allDayDefault: false,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
 disableResizing: false,
    resources: [{
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'Sara'
    }, {
  'id': '2',
  'name': 'Angela'
    }],
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
 events: '\load_events.php',
    select: function(start, end, ev) {
  console.log(ev.resources);
  var horaIni = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  var horaFin = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  if(isHoraMaxOver(end)){
   alert(mensajeHoraMax);
  }else if(isEventOverlapped(ev,horaIni,horaFin)){
   alert(mensajeOverlap);
  }else if(isDomingo(horaIni)){
   alert("Los Domingos descansamos. Lo siento");
  }else{
   createEvent(horaIni,horaFin,ev);
  }
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
  if(isAdmin()){
   modifyEvent(calEvent);
  }
    },
    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
  var start = moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  var end = moment(event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  if(isHoraMaxOver(end)){
   alert(mensajeHoraMax);
  }else if(isEventOverlapped(event,start,end)){
   alert(mensajeOverlap);
  }else if(isDomingo(start)){
   alert("Los Domingos descansamos. Lo siento");
  }else{
   $.ajax({
    url:  'update_event.php',
    data: 'fechaIni='+ start +'&fechaFin='+ end +'&id='+ event.id +'&profesional='+ event.resources,
    type: "POST"
   });
  }
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refresh');
  location.reload(true);
 },
 loading: function(bool){
  if(!bool){
   diableforInvitados();
   updateResources();
  }
 },
 eventRender: function(event, element) { 
            element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
 },
 eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  var start = moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  var end = moment(event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  if(isHoraMaxOver(end)){
   alert(mensajeHoraMax);
  }else if(isEventOverlapped(event,start,end)){
   alert(mensajeOverlap);
  }else{
   $.ajax({
    url:  'update_event.php',
    data: 'fechaIni='+ start +'&fechaFin='+ end +'&id='+ event.id,
    type: "POST"
   });
  }
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refresh');
   location.reload(true);
 }
  });
  
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');

});
```

Here is an example of a JSON feed for an event

```js
Object {id: "63", title: "mariana _", start: FCMoment, end: FCMoment, description: "manicura express esmalte normal   12mins   30.00 € <br/>"…}_allDay: false_end: FCMoment_d: Tue Nov 11 2014 21:12:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"_i: "2014-11-12T02:12:00-0500"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: true_locale: f_offset: 300_pf: Object_tzm: 300__proto__: f_id: "63"_start: FCMoment_d: Tue Nov 11 2014 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"_i: "2014-11-12T02:00:00-0500"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: true_locale: f_offset: 300_pf: Object_tzm: 300__proto__: fallDay: falseclassName: Array[0]color: "#00FF1E"description: "manicura express esmalte normal   12mins   30.00 € <br/>"end: FCMomentid: "63"resources: "1"source: Objectstart: FCMomenttitle: "mariana _"__proto__: Object
```

Here is the link for the current web page:
[Web page](http://nailsprincess.3space.info/booking/calendar.php)

Comment: is possible to have a plunker/fiddle of your code? With a .jpg is really difficult.

Comment: @thelamproject I'm also having the same problem but mine, it doesn't show the events in day view only. Do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the events were booked on a 24H format and I was capturing them under a 12H format instead. As a results those events that were booked after noon, were not being displayed within the time frame in the Day view.  Time frame: 9:00 - 20:00. E.g.: start time: 17:00 -> 5:00PM was transformed into 5AM hence it wasn't displayed.

I had to add

```
timeFormat: 'H:mm'
```

and change create_event.php

```
$fecha_inicio=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($fecha_inicio));
$fecha_fin=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($fecha_fin));
```